# Linq to entities, inner join, sort by to dictionary

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq, dictionary

Hi I am trying to convert `sql` to `linq` but I am having a trouble.

This is the sql :

```
select cc.code, cc.clientclassificationid, count(cc.code) codecount
from clientclassification cc
  inner join clientclientclassification ccc on ccc.clientclassificationid = cc.clientclassificationid
  inner join clients c on c.clientid = ccc.clientid
group by cc.code, cc.clientclassificationid
order by codecount desc
limit 4
```

This is my attempt but I am having trouble getting it to a `dictionary<int,string>`.

Can you please help?

```
var resp = (from cc in context.ClientClassifications
            join ccc in context.ClientClientClassifications on cc.ClientClassificationId equals ccc.ClientClassificationId
            join c in context.Clients on ccc.ClientId equals c.ClientId
            group c by new { cc.Code, cc.ClientClassificationId } into g
            let CodeCount = g.Key.Code.Count()
            orderby CodeCount descending
            select new
            {
                ClassificationId = g.Key.ClientClassificationId,
                Code = g.Key.Code,
            }).Take(4);
```

Comment: `var dictionary = resp.ToDictionary(x => x.ClassificationId, x => x.Code));`

Comment: Thank you for the update Silvermind. I keep getting this error though, "DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType."